# Measure execution time of sorting algorithms

Tags: c++, c++11, sorting, benchmarking

I have to measure execution time of certain sorting algorithms being passed as functions in following program. I also do not have to measure it on random container but also on ascending as well as descending sorted containers.

Header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <tuple>
#include <iomanip>

class sortT {
  private:
    std::vector<std::vector<long long>> asc;
    std::vector<std::vector<long long>> desc;
    std::vector<std::vector<long long>> random;
    unsigned int upLim; // Upperlimit 1=10, 2=100...
    void seed();
    unsigned int findSentinel(); // returns largest upperlimit possible

  public:
    // default + param constructor -> calls seed()
    sortT(unsigned int lim = 3) : upLim(lim) {
        if (upLim < 1)
            upLim = 3;
        else {
            unsigned int s = findSentinel();
            if (upLim > s) { upLim = 3; }
        }
        seed();
    };

    // exposing list in public
    std::vector<std::tuple<std::chrono::microseconds, std::chrono::microseconds,
                           std::chrono::microseconds>> list;

    void testWith(void sortF(std::vector<long long>::iterator,
                             std::vector<long long>::iterator));
    void printList();
    unsigned int getUpLim() { return upLim; }
};
```

.cpp file:

```
#include "cs-iv-algorithm.h"

unsigned int sortT::findSentinel() {

    /*
     * Get numeric limit of long long
     * normalize it by subtracting remainder
     * find out max upperlimit by clean divide of 10
    */

    long long sentinel = std::numeric_limits<long long>::max();
    sentinel = sentinel - (sentinel % 10);
    unsigned int k = 0;
    while (sentinel != 0) {
        sentinel /= 10;
        ++k;
    }
    return k;
}

void sortT::seed() {
    // reserve upLim amount of sub-vectors
    random.reserve(upLim);
    asc.reserve(upLim);
    desc.reserve(upLim);

    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= upLim; ++i) {
        unsigned int j = i;
        long long limit = 1;
        while (j != 0) {
            limit *= 10;
            --j;
        }

        // r,a,d represent sub-vectors for random,...
        std::vector<long long> r, a, d;
        r.reserve(limit);
        a.reserve(limit);
        d.reserve(limit);

        // random number generation
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 eng(rd());
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(1, 10000);

        for (long long k = 1; k <= limit; ++k) {
            r.push_back(distr(eng));
            a.push_back(k);
            d.push_back(limit - k);
        }

        random.push_back(r);
        asc.push_back(a);
        desc.push_back(d);
    }
}

void sortT::testWith(void sortF(std::vector<long long>::iterator,
                                std::vector<long long>::iterator)) {
    unsigned int i = 0;

    while (i < upLim) {
        auto tp1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        sortF(random[i].begin(), random[i].end());
        auto tp2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration1 =
            std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(tp2 - tp1);

        tp1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        sortF(asc[i].begin(), asc[i].end());
        tp2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration2 =
            std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(tp2 - tp1);

        tp1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        sortF(desc[i].begin(), desc[i].end());
        tp2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration3 =
            std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(tp2 - tp1);

        list.push_back(std::make_tuple(duration1, duration2, duration3));
        ++i;
    }
}

void sortT::printList() {
    unsigned int i = 1;

    std::cout << std::left;
    std::cout << std::setw(10) << "Iteration" << std::setw(0) << "|\t";
    std::cout << std::setw(10) << "limit" << std::setw(0) << "|\t";
    std::cout << std::setw(10) << "RandomBox" << std::setw(0) << "|\t";
    std::cout << std::setw(10) << "AscBox" << std::setw(0) << "|\t";
    std::cout << std::setw(10) << "DescBox" << std::setw(0) << "|\t";

    for (auto &listTuple : list) {

        unsigned int j = i;
        long long limit = 1;
        while (j > 0) {
            limit *= 10;
            --j;
        }

        std::cout << "\n";
        std::cout << std::setw(10) << i << std::setw(0) << "|\t";
        std::cout << std::setw(10) << limit << std::setw(0) << "|\t";
        std::cout << std::setw(10) << std::get<0>(listTuple).count()
                  << std::setw(0) << "|\t";
        std::cout << std::setw(10) << std::get<1>(listTuple).count()
                  << std::setw(0) << "|\t";
        std::cout << std::setw(10) << std::get<2>(listTuple).count()
                  << std::setw(0) << "|\t";

        ++i;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

For now I've implemented it only for integers and I'm looking forward to implement it for floating point type too. Under current implementation, I'm exposing the `list` vector so that a dev can view and clear according to his/her needs. I've also included a temporarily print function to show the results. I would like to know what design improvements can be made on following code or any other suggestion you might like to give.

Here is an alternative [repo](https://github.com/agauniyal/cs-iv-algorithm) that contains test file too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, there isn't much to say and I can't find any obvious flow at first sight. I'll have to comment on small things instead:

- This signature struck me as begin rather restrictive:

  ```
  void testWith(void sortF(std::vector<long long>::iterator,
                           std::vector<long long>::iterator));
  ```

  I understand that you only test vector sorting algorithms, but you could have the function type as a template parameter instead:

  ```
  template<typename BinaryFunction>
  void testWith(BinaryFunction sortF);
  ```

  And still call it like that:

  ```
  sortF(random[i].begin(), random[i].end());
  ```

  This would allow you to use function objects too and to use generic functions not especially designed to sort vectors, but that can still sort a vector.
- You could avoid duplication with a dedicated function to time *one* function at a time:

  ```
  template<typename Function>
  auto timeIt(Function function)
      -> std::chrono::microseconds
  {
      auto tp1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      function();
      auto tp2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(tp2 - tp1);
  }
  ```

  Then you could reimplement `testWith` with a few lambdas to simplify things:

  ```
  template<typename BinaryFunction>
  void sortT::testWith(BinaryFunction sortF) {
      for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < upLim ; ++i) {
          auto duration1 = timeIt([]{
              sortF(random[i].begin(), random[i].end());
          });

          auto duration2 = timeIt([]{
              sortF(asc[i].begin(), asc[i].end());
          });

          auto duration3 = timeIt([]{
              sortF(desc[i].begin(), desc[i].end());
          });

          list.push_back(std::make_tuple(duration1, duration2, duration3));
      }
  }
  ```

  Note that I also rewrote your algorithm with a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop. When you have severa tools at hand, try to pick the most suitable one for the job. Actually, it would make sense for most of your `while` loops to be replaced by `for` loops.
- By the way, instead of constructing an `std::tuple` and pushing it into `list`, you could directly create it into `list` with `emplace_back`:

  ```
  list.emplace_back(duration1, duration2, duration3);
  ```
- Also, since you know that your `list` will only ever contain instances of `std::chrono::microseconds`, you might want to use an `std::array<std::chrono::microseconds, 3u>` instead of the more verbose `std::tuple<std::chrono::microseconds, std::chrono::microseconds, std::chrono::microseconds>`. It will make your code easier to expand and to read.
- I speak of expanding the code since you probably want to add a pipe organ test case to your tests since some sorting algorithms are known to perform poorly with pipe organ patterns.
- `const`-correctness is important in C++ semantics. If one of your functions does not alter the class members, then mark it `const`:

  ```
  unsigned int getUpLim() const { return upLim; }
  ```
- Instead of having a `printList` method, it would be more idiomatic to overload `operator<<` between `std::ostream&` and `sortT` so that you can print your list to any output stream instead of simply `std::cout`.
- When possible, try to use compound assignment operators to make your code shorter and hypothetically more performant. For example, turn this line:

  ```
  sentinel = sentinel - (sentinel % 10);
  ```

  into this one:

  ```
  sentinel -= sentinel % 10;
  ```
- Instead of reinitializing your random number engine everytime you call `seed`, you could let it live its life once initialized since it should still produce different results everytime `seed` is invoked:

  ```
  // random number generation
  thread_local std::random_device rd;
  thread_local std::mt19937 eng(rd());
  thread_local std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(1, 10000);
  ```

  Making the instances `thread_local` make sure there is one instance per thread. It makes generating random numbers inherently thread-safe while not having to initialize the engine again everytime you call `seed`.

Comment: Can't be bothered to write an answer so I'll just append to Morvenn's. :) You should discard the first run of the benchmark to remove any effects of  cache warmup.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to try not to duplicate anything from [Morwenn's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/98106/16369) in mine.

---

Your function `sortT::findSentinel` takes 16 lines to implement the equivalent of

```
int sortT::findSentinel() {
    return 1 + std::numeric_limits<long long>::digits10;
}
```

Once we write it in the shorter way, it's easy to see that your version has a bug: when `upLim == findSentinel()`, you try to compute 10<sup>19</sup> as a `long long`, which invokes undefined behavior. To fix the bug, we need to remove the `1 +` from the code above.

But of course even before that, it probably fails the preceding iteration's attempt to allocate 10<sup>18</sup> bytes of memory, so you'll never see the undefined behavior in practice.

Solution: Replace `findSentinel` with a reasonable constant such as `8`, and constant-propagate it into the `sortT` constructor.

```
sortT(int lim = 3) :
    upLim(std::min(std::max(1, lim), 8))  // 10^8 should be enough for anybody
{
    seed();
}
```

---

This:

```
    random.push_back(r);
    asc.push_back(a);
    desc.push_back(d);
```

makes *copies* of the large vectors `r`, `a`, and `d`. Prefer to move them into place:

```
    random.emplace_back(std::move(r));
    asc.emplace_back(std::move(a));
    desc.emplace_back(std::move(d));
```

Or of course you could just make `r` a *reference* to the appropriate member of `random` from the beginning:

```
void sortT::seed() {
    random.resize(upLim);
    asc.resize(upLim);
    desc.resize(upLim);

    std::mt19937 eng(std::random_device()());

    long long limit = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < upLim; ++i) {
        limit *= 10;

        auto& r = random[i];
        auto& a = asc[i];
        auto& d = desc[i];

        a.resize(limit);
        std::iota(a.begin(), a.end(), 1);

        d.resize(limit);
        std::generate(d.begin(), d.end(), [k=limit]() mutable { return k--; });

        r.resize(limit);
        std::generate(r.begin(), r.end(),
            [&]() {
                return std::uniform_int_distribution<>(1,1000)(eng);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

The above code is too clever for its own good, so let's refactor one more time:

```
        a.resize(limit);
        for (int j=0; j < limit; ++j) a[j] = j + 1;

        d.resize(limit);
        for (int j=0; j < limit; ++j) d[j] = limit - j;

        r.resize(limit);
        for (int j=0; j < limit; ++j) r[j] = std::uniform_int_distribution<>(1, 1000)(eng);
```

Yeah, that's nicer.

---

One more important point about code organization: Your .h file starts off with the lines

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <tuple>
#include <iomanip>
```

This is terrible! You're making every user of your .h file import all those headers, even though they probably won't be used. You should `#include` only the small set of headers that your own code actually requires.

Then, in your .cpp file, you should `#include` whatever headers *that* code requires. For example, since your .cpp file uses `std::random_device`, you should `#include <random>` in your .cpp file — and since your .h file does *not* use anything from `<random>`, your .h file should *not* `#include <random>`. Makes sense, right?

Comment: Is there any advantage in this case to change `push_back` into `emplace_back`? Since `push_back` already has an rvalue-reference constructor, I fail to see what `emplace_back` adds here.

Comment: I didn't make a conscious choice; after thinking about it, I think you're right that `push_back` would be equivalent in this case. In general I prefer to use the `emplace` spellings whenever possible, just for consistency's sake. (I also prefer `++i` over `i++` whenever possible, just for consistency's sake, because it's more efficient on *some* types, and I don't want to be bothered thinking about which case I'm currently in.)

Comment: I want to award bounty on both answers but I'm not able to do so. This answer is written very well and thankyou for that :)